# I am new to Stack Overflow. Is there help content that I can refer to?

Tags: support, help-center

I am new here and would like to contribute to this question:

[Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error?answertab=active#tab-top)

But I can't find the answer box.

How can I know if it is closed?

One of the answers has helped me solve the issue in my project, which I wanted to comment my piece of code, but because I am new and don't have enough reputations, it won't let me comment. OK, but how about reply?

Is there a help document or anything on how to use Stack Overflow for newbies like me?

Comment: Question mark in the upper right should bring you to the help centre.

Comment: Do not post "answers" to reply or say "thank you". if you contribute to the site, for example with some suggested edits, an actual and good answer or a reasonable question, you'll be able to gain some reputation to up-vote which is our way to say "thank you". On SO you have to unlearn some of the habits obtained on social media platforms.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You can look it up here: https://stackoverflow.com/help , but if you need it,
the shortcut icon is located on the top of the page (second from the left).

> [image]

---

When it comes to the question that you want to answer...
When I go there I see this button

> [image]

on the very bottom of the page. And when you try adding an answer this message pops up:

> [image]

So there wasn't a "normal input form" thus you didn't notice the "Answer" button.

Comment: That button only appears for you because you're above 10 rep. The OP is at 1 rep and the question is protected. That is stated in the post notice (since today those appear at the top, in a blue-ish style)

Answer (score 20):

The reason that you cannot contribute an answer is that that question has been flagged as "protected".  In short, this means that users with less than 10 reputation points cannot answer it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions for more information on why some questions are protected, and what it means.

In this case, someone with high reputation (15K or more) has made the call that there are already too many answers for this question.  Further contributions at this point are likely to be duplicative and not helpful to readers.

This is probably a bit frustrating for you.  (Especially if you have read all of the existing answers and you have something new and important to contribute.)  My advice is to bookmark the question, and answer it when you have earned some reputation from up-votes on other questions and answers.